# How to prevent disclosure icons from auto hiding and auto showing in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and the disclosure icons inside the program are invisible until I move the mouse over them. I would like the icons to be visible at all times. I can't tell if this is a Windows feature or a Eclipse feature.

FYI On OSX (Mac) the same program shows the disclosure icons at all times.

disclosure icons hidden during inactivity:

[image]

disclosure icons shown after mouse move:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is an Eclipse issue. Am I correct in assuming these arrows indicate sub-trees that can be expanded when the arrow is clicked?

Comment: I don't remember seeing it in any other program than Eclipse so far. And yes. If there is an disclosure icon it indicates it is a branch node.

Comment: Some applications use + signs, some use the right-arrow. It's a rather common UI feature. Have you checked the Eclipse support forums or known issues reports?